# MongoDB PHP error connection timeout

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

[image: connection timeout occurs on mongodb connect]

connection timeout occurs and shows this error. php mongo driver is installed and information shown in phpinfo().

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
```

this is the only code written

[image]

i am using PHP7.0 VC14 and Xampp Apache2

please give me a solution

Comment: have u started xampp and apache server?

Comment: yes, thats why i show the php_info()

Comment: And have you started the mongo db service (mongod)?

Comment: I think this problem is related to MongoDB drivers. You can install it with composer.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: yes Luiz, i did it